# Rails group validation with just one error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

The following validation code in the model:

```
validates :formatted_address, :zip, :city, :state, :country, :presence => true, :message => "is incomplete. Please enter full address."
```

is displayed when either of the fields are empty. Let's say now `:address` and `country` are empty, 2 errors are displayed:

```
Formatted Address is incomplete. Please enter full address.
Country is incomplete. Please enter full address.
```

How can I group the error message in the validation to just show one error message if either of the fields validated does not exist?

```
Address is incomplete. Please enter full address.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write your own validator using the [`validate` macro](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods):

```
validate :has_complete_address

#...

private
def has_complete_address
    # Check that everything is there and
    # call self.errors.add to store an error
    # message if something is wrong.
end
```